# How to fetch SSL cert subject, issuer, start date and expire date from the trust.p12 cert file

Tags: file, ssl-certificate, websphere-8, p12

> Environment - IBM websphere application server 8.5.5
>
> File - trust.p12 and key.p12 (in trust.p12 , 20 certificates are
>   added)
>
> by using openssl commnd, i can able to see complete certificate
>   details like below

MAC Iteration 2048 MAC verified OK PKCS7 Encrypted data:
pbeWithSHA1And40BitRC2-CBC, Iteration 2048 Certificate bag Bag
Attributes
    localKeyID: XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX 48 54 A0 47 88 1D 90
    friendlyName: test-server subject=/C=US/ST=IC/L=test/O=XXX Security/OU=XXX/CN=something1 issuer=/C=US/ST=IC/L=test/O=XXX
Security/OU=XXXX/CN=something1
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----- ... ... ...
-----END CERTIFICATE-----

Certificate bag Bag Attributes
    localKeyID: XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX
    friendlyName: root subject=/C=US/ST=IC/L=test/O=XXX /OU=XXX/CN=testroot issuer=/C=US/ST=IC/L=test/O=XXX
/OU=XXXX/CN=testroot
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----- ... ... ...
-----END CERTIFICATE-----

> But i tried to fetch subject, issuer, start date and expire date from
>   the trust.p12 cert file by using below commands.
>
> **1st Method**
>
> openssl pkcs12 -in trust.p12 -nokeys | openssl x509 -noout
>
> -dates -subject -issuer -alias
>
> **2nd Method**
>
> openssl pkcs12 -in trust.p12 -out trust.pem -nodes
>
> cat trust.pem | openssl x509 -noout -enddate
>
> however i'm getting output for 1 certificate alone instead of 20
>   certificates trough above commands.
>
> 1) Is there any other way to fetch 20 certificate one by one something
>   like by passing alias name?
>
> 2) How to fetch subject, issuer, start date and expire date for 20 certificate one by one?

Answer (score 0):

How about, if this could be done in java. You need to know the alias for all the 20 certificates and defined it as a string array.

Also you define alias as a config file so that if alias changes in future, you don't have to change the code.

```
static List<X509Certificate> certList = new ArrayList<>();
public static void main(String[] args) throws KeyStoreException
{
    String[] alias = { "1","2"};
    KeyStore keyStore = getKeyStore();
    for (int i = 0; i < alias.length; i++) {
        X509Certificate certFromKeyStore = (X509Certificate) keyStore.getCertificate(alias[i]);
        System.out.println(certFromKeyStore.getSubjectDN());
        certList.add(certFromKeyStore);
    }
    for (X509Certificate x509 : certList) {
        // verify all the information you looking for
        System.out.println(x509.getSerialNumber() + " "+ x509.getIssuerDN() );
    }
}

public static KeyStore getKeyStore()
{
    KeyStore keyStore = null;
    try
    {
        keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
        InputStream input = new FileInputStream("PATHTOP12");
        keyStore.load(input, "YOUR_P12_PASSWORD".toCharArray());
    } catch (Exception e) 
    {
        // catch the exception 
    }
    return keyStore;
}
```

Let me know if this helps.
Are you specifically looking this to be done in openssl ?

Comment: Thanks. Let me check. But this is possible in openssl.. i need output like below CN from subject, cn from issuer, start date and date

Comment: I'm expecting output in openssl.